# Projectiles Wont Change Into An Image Error How To Fix?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pygame

so I made a projectile class and tried to change it into an image but I am getting this error

```
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\PYTHONGGAME\py.py", line 320, in <module>
    bullet.draw(window)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\PYTHONGGAME\py.py", line 20, in draw
    window.blit(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit
```

my projectiles class

```
class projectile(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 8
        self.slash = pygame.image.load("slash_03.png")
    def draw(self,win):
        window.blit(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)
```

this part V is using keys to display the projectile and move it

```
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:     
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x += bullet.speed 
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        if len(bullets) < 2:  
            bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2), round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:     
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x -= bullet.speed 
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        if len(bullets) < 2:  
            bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2), round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))
```

my full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

plat = pygame.image.load("gt.png")
coinss = pygame.image.load("coin_gold.png")
slash = pygame.image.load("slash_03.png")

class projectile(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 8
        self.slash = pygame.image.load("slash_03.png")
    def draw(self,win):
        window.blit(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)

# the enemy
class enes:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)







# color for enems
green = (63, 190, 22)
enems1 = enes(350,259,50,50, green)
florida = [enems1]

# player class
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color 
        self.d_indesx = 0
        self.s_index = 0
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.speed = 5
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction = "left"
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)






# platforms
class platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.plat = pygame.image.load("gt.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,plat.get_width(), plat.get_height())
        self.plat = pygame.transform.scale(self.plat,(self.plat.get_width()//2,self.plat.get_height()//2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.plat,self.rect)

# Coins
class coin:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.coinss = pygame.image.load("coin_gold.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,coinss.get_width(), coinss.get_height())
        self.plat = pygame.transform.scale(self.coinss,(self.coinss.get_width()//2,self.coinss.get_height()//2))
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.coinss,self.rect)


# Floor
class floor:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
score = 0
text = font.render('Gold  = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()  
textRect.center = (100, 40)

# enemy
Sfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
Kills = 0
Stext = Sfont.render('Kills  = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
textRectS = Stext.get_rect()  
textRectS.center = (400, 100)


# fps
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# colors
Green = (63, 190, 22)
Blue = (22, 190, 175)
white = (240, 240, 240)

# define the enemy player coin classes
playerman = player(40,390,30,30, Blue)
enemy1 = platform(150,390,190,10, Green)
enemy2 = platform(300,310,190,10, Green)
enemy3 = platform(80,260,190,10, Green)
enemy4 = platform(250,180,190,10, Green)
enemy5 = platform(490,120,190,10, Green)
enemy6 = platform(-50,100,190,10, Green)
enemy7 = platform(180,50,190,10, Green)
platforms = [enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4,enemy5,enemy6,enemy7]

# coin class
coin1 = coin(180,320,50,50, Green)
coin2 = coin(350,250,50,50, Green)
coin3 = coin(150,200,50,50, Green)


Coins_list = [coin1,coin2,coin3]

# floor class
floor1 = floor(-1000,490,9999,50, white)
flories = [floor1]

#main loop
bullets = []
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False


    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.y += playerman.speed
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y += playerman.speed
        for floor in flories:
            floor.y += playerman.speed
        for enes in florida:
            enes.y += playerman.speed




    if playerman.y > 450:

        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.y -= playerman.fall
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y -= playerman.fall
        for floor in flories:
            floor.y -= playerman.fall
        for enes in florida:
            enes.y -= playerman.fall





    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:     
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x += bullet.speed 
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        if len(bullets) < 2:  
            bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2), round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:     
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x -= bullet.speed 
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        if len(bullets) < 2:  
            bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2), round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerman.direction = "left"
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
        if playerman.x < 100:
            playerman.x += playerman.speed
            for platform in platforms:
                platform.x += playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x += playerman.speed
            for enes in florida:
                enes.x += playerman.speed


    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerman.direction = "right"
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
        if playerman.x > 400:
            playerman.x -= playerman.speed
            for platform in platforms:
                platform.x -= playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x -= playerman.speed
            for enes in florida:
                enes.x -= playerman.speed




    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False
        collide = False
        for platform in platforms:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = platform.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = platform.rect.right


            for i in range(len(Coins_list)-1,-1,-1):
                if playerman.rect.colliderect(Coins_list[i].rect):
                    del Coins_list[i]
                    score += 1
                    text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
                    textRect = text.get_rect()  
                    textRect.center = (100, 40)





        for floor in flories:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(floor.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = floor.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > floor.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < floor.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < floor.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > floor.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor.rect.right






            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.JumpCount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

            if collide:
                if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    playerman.isJump = True
                playerman.fall = 0


    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.isJump = False

    window.fill((74, 107, 104))
    enems1.draw()
    window.blit(Stext,textRectS)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(window)
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    for platform in platforms:
        platform.draw()
    for coin in Coins_list:
        coin.draw()
    playerman.draw()
    for floor in flories:
        floor.draw()



    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm wrong but the [definition](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) to the function blit is :

```
blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags=0) -> Rect
```

So it doesn't match with your call:

```
window.blit(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)
```

Try to call it with the matching argument :

```
window.blit(win, (self.x,self.y))
```

Comment: thats what I have done and still get that error   File "C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\PYTHONGGAME\py.py", line 20, in draw
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit
>>>

Comment: ok um I tried this:      window.blit(win, (self.color (self.x,self.y)), self.radius) and now I am getting an error that says                         File "C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\PYTHONGGAME\py.py", line 20, in draw
    window.blit(win, (self.color (self.x,self.y)), self.radius)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable